# Import 50+ tables from MySQL to SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, import, ssis

I need too import more than 50 tables from a MySQL database. the connection details are known and I'm able to connect after creating a dsn using connection details. When I try to use the Import Export Wizard however, there are some type conversion issues i need to individually address(Eg: Destination type is shown as '22' or '13').

This is cumbersome for 50+ tables. Is there an easier alternative to this? I just need the data in string format in my MSSQL tables.

Comment: Yakshemash ! Yes, you can use SSIS to do the job. Create a dynamic database connection in SSIS for this. Google it. I am not really in the mood for taking the screenshots and making the huge answer your question needs. Chenqui.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use the DataConversion data flow transformer. It's easy to use and configure. You can use it to get the data (almost) in the same format/data types as in the MySQL db. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would start from the Import Export Wizard, then save the resulting SSIS Package and edit it using Visual Studio / BIDS / SSDT BI.

In the real world you often need to "individually address" specific issues, so the above steps meet that challenge quickly, with a minimal amount of coding.